# Crease edge not working

Tags: edges

I am following a tutorial where the tutor creases the edges with "Mean crease" set to 1. I am doing the same with Blender 2.8, but it is not working as expected. The edges crease a little bit, but does not get sharp.

I am having same amount of polys

Answer (score 2):

Creasing has more to do with how subdivision surfaces interpret the edges, once a subdivision surface modifier is applied, see gif for demonstration.

[image]

If creasing isn't what you're after and you're trying to create a smoothing split by marking edges as sharp, you're going to want to do the following:

1. Select your object, and access 'Object Data' in the properties panel, and enable 'Auto Smooth'.

[image]

2. Increase the Auto Smooth angle to 180 (or any preferred value).
3. In edit mode, highlight the edges you want to mark as sharp and press CTRL+E (for edge actions), and choose 'Mark Sharp'.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Trill. I am following the Jeep Wrangle course from Chris Plush. I am following it using 2.8 (not sure if this makes a difference). He is using the Subdiv modifier and after that he will tweak the mean crease to make the subdiv inactive in certain edges. In my case the "sharpness" will not get as the one he is performing.

I am interested to understand the difference between the two techniques you propose. Ultimately I would like to understand why the technique offered in the video tutorial is not working in my file. 
Thanks a lot