# Edge Crease or Sharp Edge being ignored by Subdivision surface

Tags: subdivision-surface

I'm trying to get subdivision to work only on the inner circle. So I applied a crease and sharp edge on the 4 sides of the square but it seems to get ignored. I got this idea from this thread https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/128571/142292 and I already set the crease to 1.0 but it doesn't work. Also [Keep sharp edges when using subdivision surface](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6425/keep-sharp-edges-when-using-subdivision-surface) and [Forcing a flat edge when using the subdivision surface modifier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/237319/forcing-a-flat-edge-when-using-the-subdivision-surface-modifier) do not work for me.

[image]

Comment: it would work with this solution, which means you need to create an additional edge loop: https://zupimages.net/up/22/49/8b54.jpg

Comment: oooh so i set the wrong edges as crease edges! cool it works! thanks so much! if you add it as answer i will accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would work with the edge crease on the obliques, but you need to create an additional edge loop:

[image]

*Edge Crease* indicates where you don't want the roudness to happen, as if you used support edges. If you added an edge loop along the outer edges, it would not sharp these outer edges:

[image]

Whereas if you bevelled the obliques it would sharp these outer edges:

[image]

Comment: aweome. it's funny though that i apparently used the wrong edge as crease. i don't understand why i have to set the diagonal edge though XD

Comment: I've edited and tried to explain, I'm not too familiar with edge creases though